# Retrieve "Alias" using Java EWS API

Tags: java, exchange-server, alias, exchangewebservices

I am trying to find out the "Alias" of a contact/room.

Is it anyway possible to retrieve it via the java ews api. If not, is there another alternative e.g. the EWS SOAP Web Services?

Currently I am only receiving mail address, company name, display name, department and office location ...
That would suggest, when I fill out the information in the contact form (see image below) this information should also be retrieved through the EWS API. But "Alias" is missing.

[image]

I searched for the alias Information in those java objects. Especially the "PropertyBag" Class. "getAlias()" returns null.

```
        NameResolution nameResolution = nameResolutionIterator.next();

        Contact contact = nameResolution.getContact();
        contact.getAlias(); // This one returns null..
        PropertyBag propertyBag = contact.getPropertyBag();
        Collection<Object> propertiesValues = propertyBag.getProperties()
                .values();
        Set<PropertyDefinition> propertiesKeys = propertyBag
                .getProperties().keySet();
```

Comment: If the Java managed API is similar to the C# one, maybe you need to load the property before you can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Exchange 2010 SP2 (or later) installed  you can use the ContactDataShape property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa565329(v=exchg.150).aspx which was added in SP2 to tell exchange to return this property. Eg the following will work in Sp2 and later

```
        PropertySet psPropSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
        NameResolutionCollection coll = service.ResolveName("glen", ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly,true , psPropSet);
        foreach (NameResolution nameRes in coll)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Contact name: " + nameRes.Contact.Alias);
        }
```

Cheers
Glen